# Can belongings of the Prophet (SAWW) cure blindness?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, tafseer

[Quran says](http://tanzil.net/#12:93):

The blind eyes of prophet Jacob a.s. was miraculously healed by a dead Shirt.

That shirt was belonging of prophet Joseph a.s.

The shirt was a dead thing (not an alive prophet) and Quran and hadith do not say the miracles are finished for us.

According to the fact that rank of our Prophet SAWW is higher than all other prophets, is it possible that the belongings of our Prophet SAWW in the current era can heal blindness too?

*Please answer based on Quran and hadith.*

Answer (score 6):

Only Allah heals!
What Allah did with Yusuf was to show his blessings. God may do whatever he wants with the method he chooses. No cloth or even a man can heal or do out of Allah's willing.

A believer seeks healthiness from Allah, and follow available medicine according to our prophets teachings.

Answer (score 5):

This was a miracle for Prophet Yusuf (peace be upon him) and the rank of the two Prophet's doesn't have anything to do with it.  There are no Authentic Ahadeeth which mention that the Prophet's belongings can heal blindness.  And Allah knows best.

Comment: Prophet Yusuf a.s. was at another country. and what made the healing was the shirt. Sahaba used belonging of prophet SAWW for healing. for example his wudu water or his cloths. support your answer with references.

Comment: @DavidWallace Minor correction: He doesn't need instruments.

Comment: @DavidWallace The reason I said it was not possible is that there were no authentic ahadeeth (as far as I know) which says that his belongings can or should be used to heal blindness, anyway I have edited it out of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, if u find a true wali of ALLAH. wali from the izan of Holy Prophet saww can do such things. such unexpected things are known as "karamat"